# cannot able to pass data from express to ejs?

Tags: mysql, express, ejs

i tried to pass a data from js file(sample.js) to ejs  using `res.send("filename.ejs",data`) by converting a object into JSON where JSON data is displaying on console, but while trying to pass it showing an error

> TypeError: Cannot create property '_locals' on string

can some one help with this and tell me how to call them in ejs file

Comment: Please consider making an [edit] to clarify your question. In the meantime, if you need to send the contents of a file from your node/express server to ejs in your browser, try `res.sendFile()`. https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: As O. Jones said, we really need a lot more information. Can you attach your code and describe the output you expect from the client in detail?

Answer (score 0):

res.send() is used for send data there is no need to point ejs file

res.send takes array as parameter (res.send([body])) and you can get it in ejs like {{ data }}

for example

NODEJS
    res.send({message: 'hello'})

filename.ejs

```
<div>{{ message }}</div> or <%= JSON.stringify(message)  %>
```

also as Express 5x does not support `res.send()` method you can use

```
res.status(200).send({message: 'hello})
```

(you did not admit you express version)

Answer (score 0):

You're sending data to your view so update your code with this and try

```
   res.render("filename",{
                        data:"hello"
                      });
```

Or you can pass whole data

```
 res.render("filename",{data:data});
```

And in your ejs file access it like this

```
 <div> <%= data %> <div>
```

Comment: You can't use `.ejs` in the filename when using `res.render('filename')`...

Answer (score 0):

Note that you should **not** use the `.ejs` extension in `res.render`, despite other answers to your question suggesting that you do so.
When you call `res.render('myView')`, ejs looks for a template called `myView.ejs` in a folder called `views` (which is set as the default folder to use by ejs)

for example:

```
res.render('myView.ejs',{
  data:data,
  foo:'foo'
});
```

ejs will look for a view called `myView.ejs.ejs` (or it might just fail alltogether).

To access the data on your template, you would do the following:

app.js:

```
app.get('/somePathHere', function(req, res) {
  res.render('myView',{
    data:data,
    foo:'foo'
  });
});
```

myView.ejs:

```
<% data.forEach(function(item) { %>
    //do something

<% }); %>

<%= foo %>
```

**Note** that when accessing a variable, you use the `<%= varNameHere %>`, and when writing any type of function, you would omit the `=`.